Scraping data from website with multiple steps to get to the data and that prevent scraping
I'm trying to scrape data from the following website:
https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfe/consulta-completa
STEP 1

STEP 2
When the Access Key is inserted I need to press the "Pesquisar" button:
In this case I've used the following access key:
52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252

and it returns the following page:
https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/xml-consulta-completa?g-recaptcha-response=03AFcWeA7_oqqL4KubId8rW_TapI_NSJDOGBzrx_JB2XAtJitNaBl23zLKbjbj45m9eUZam3xp6R57BI47AI0lp_K3KS-CbtpPiTNAHqcxLV-Gnp2Vf778i3NeLMCKNoHpk7IitkwPHvHJjkg1sWRqdTZrHkhVHiMwFbTC4qFw6436ddwu9rRERxOiY532lIoijoHzDga85l7RvbHkyGUdWD7QVlTUNUU-2ztx21cQ_pDDQrxreDFEL8eCR0ijYAMrOtKEXMwqGSuHFTOSkZ83DCJ4S610YWujUukTXbOSdaAuGpeHljf4CsswFLWTKN8UoKTjlEia_I0cO17zgSnY9Z9rQDEZR1Xeq00CDmpbB73m95EOo0prSrL2RcsRnWkPytDIwJUIfsEAcEQ77vuacbNflj_yFpj2GSWVnGQnKXUrY4DsyRhNU6T6usZaYH5kTRb85qvrfm2FqOlgBfLDcvuwB_Q2JqRxyF6-oJlw64Sx2MZzUQC2gZjPtAIRwGCqOS80OkDkTmHZl9x3fM6tOr4fYM6BouHWrnjfyNz99O9bFcQv_bbdyREr1MVgJ6fujSZM6C7WoRJjwTv29kIuGc2l4nMkkilUU6rzK-apAYtgzSim_5T6N_zkvVQfOAo0mlKwjfVLVxCaWQYsGe5MfBe65ZmLVP_lIHnsJe_z0G9CMclmpaKTiynNEMtu_n8d6utw5ot6BHGp9OALHQq2_62hE_TTYMqVlrzugaPxMrTMKnGWd4W_kVPh-VqgqsKxdDW8xFXYtE8OM_WZNRg4m0ESnl4xW5NLZeZGu7onPt3jkw3vCt57YmdAgcHPpIhg0zPA7lNdBrY1zCeCM3edWoatnFng6irasc5R8fheSL2IS0lSUqCfN_cIuC6rYlPUGlU7pREqYe5ZTxHNkyI6GBvWM_pZSO4glw&chaveAcesso=52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252


STEP 3
In this stage I need to click in the "Visualizar NFC-e Detalhada" to finally get to the page with the data I want to scrape.
The new path becomes:
https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/NFCe?chNFe=52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252


The final step is to click in "Produtos e Serviços"
Which will bring me to the following screen where is the data I want to scrape:

Errors
If i try to access the webpage directly from the link: https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/NFCe?chNFe=52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252
it returns session expired:

If I try to scrape via python, it blocks me and i can't make any more search, even if it's via web browser.
I need help on trying to scrape the data in that specific page, following all the steps and bypassing the recaptcha and bot block from the web site security.

The website may be blocking you because it's trying to stop scraping.
However, the following code works for me even after multiple attempts:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from functools import cache

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")

url = "https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfe/consulta-completa"
access_key = "52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252"

@cache
def wait(driver):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def click(driver, selector):
    button = wait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))
    ActionChains(driver).click(button).perform()

def send(driver, selector, data):
    wait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector)).send_keys(data)

def text(e):
    return e.text if e.text else e.get_attribute("textContent")

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    send(driver, (By.ID, "chaveAcesso"), access_key)
    click(driver, (By.ID, "btnPesquisar"))
    click(driver, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-view-det"))
    click(driver, (By.ID, "tab_3"))
    # Now scrape the page. For example, print the text for a selection of labels
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.col-4 td label"
    for label in wait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(selector)):
        print(text(label))

Output:
Base de Cálculo ICMS
Valor do ICMS
Valor do ICMS Desonerado
Valor Total do FCP
Código do Produto
Código NCM
Código CEST


Thanks for the response! I could replicate the same results as you!
I needed to insert another button click and now im getting anotherr error:
I've switch click(driver, (By.ID, "tab_3")) with click(driver, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button-print")) and "tr.col-4 td label" with "fixo-prod-serv-descricao"  now I'm getting the followint error on those two new lines:
File [...]\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:105, in ``WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
104     time.sleep(self._poll)
--> 105 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

@RooseveltJr "button-print" is not appropriate as a CSS selector because there is no such element

There is this element: <button class="btn btn-default button-print responsive-field">Impressão Completa</button> which I want to click

Nevermind! I've made it work! I Have set your response as correct! Thanks for the help.

@RooseveltJr The CSS selector for that element is "button.button-print". You may need additional classes in the selector to guarantee that you only get the button of interest - i.e., there may be other buttons with the "button-print" class

You can use a data scraping approach with selenium and beautifulsoup4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# WebDriverWait timeout in second
timeout = 10

# initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # activate headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# initialize web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# access target page
driver.get("https://nfeweb.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfe/consulta-completa")

# using WebDriverWait 
try:
    # get the specific input element
    input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "chaveAcesso"))
    )
    # fill the input
    input_box.send_keys("52241061585865236600650040001896941930530252")
    
    # get the specific button for step 1
    submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnPesquisar"))
    )
    # click the button
    submit_button.click()
    
    # get the specific button for step 2
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-view-det"))
    )
    # click the button
    next_button.click()
    
    # get the specific element with id "tab_3" (Produtos e Serviços) tab
    target_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tab_3"))
    )
    # click the element
    target_tab.click()
    
    # You can use your beautifulsoup4 script to scrape data here... 
    
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
    # close the web driver
    driver.quit()

The code above uses the Chrome web driver in headless mode. If you want to see the process in progress, you can change the line
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

to
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


You just add logic to scrape content according to your needs after the target_tab.click() section
